# Area between two curves with a certain domain.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, area

I am trying to find the area between two curves over a certain domain. The region of integration is between $xy=5$, $x=9-y^2$ and the lines $y=1$ and $y=2$. I have to show that this can be written as both a single and double integral and then I have to find the area.

So far I have set up the integral $\int_{1}^{2} \int_{5/y}^{9-y^2} 1 \;dx\, dy$ but I am not sure what to do from there.

Comment: To evaluate the double integral, integrate first with respect to $x$ which is the inner product, then with respect to $y$.